# Updating new files in a external disk

Tags: files, external-hdd

I bought a 750GB external hard disk a couple months ago. So the first time I copied all my stuff (documents, photos, music ...).

After a while I wanted to update the data in my external disk, but I didn't remember exactly which files did I create, modify or delete since the last update. So I just ended up deleting everything from the external hard disk and coping everything back in.

There has to be a better solution right? Something that acts like a version controller.

Comment: Version Controller for Documents, photos, music seems new to me.Does copy & paste doesn't gives you Overwrite files option. I am confused by the question.

Comment: The overwrite option is just like coping it all back in (just overwrites everything without checking if it was modified or not)

Answer (score 0):

For Data files [Documents, photos, music ,etc] the logical method would be by replacing the older files with the new one by considering the info parameters for example:Date of creation of Modification.I guess you will have to write a script for that to do your job.

OR

Alternately by removing the duplicate files after copying or merging the new ones.
For reference script like [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=647883) ,which searches for the duplicate files and merges over old files.

For GIU purpose there is [fdupes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59107/find-duplicate-files-and-folders-and-move-these-to-a-different-folder) and also Fslint to do it manually.