# Too many images in one directory

Tags: jpeg

I have a directory with half a million JPEG files and it can't be opened in Nautilus. What is the simplest way to see the previews of these images?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: select folder with shotwell and let shotwell create folder dates and such

Comment: Split the images into multiple directories. You aren't going to view all 500000 previews anyway.

Comment: I just want to see what is inside the directory. Like how the pictures look like. With Nautilus I cant do that because it freezes. I tried Shotwell and it is now importing the images (without copying). It is performing very very slow though.

Comment: You have half a million images. Its gonna take some time, when shotwell is done you can view them by using shotwell. or via nautilus

Comment: @blade19899 You should post that first comment as an answer, especially if it works. To the OP: Are there *many* duplicates? That's a lot of files and you might [try de-duplicating](http://askubuntu.com/q/3865/12864) first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select folder with [Shotwell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell/), and let Shotwell create folder dates and such.

as @Tom Brosmann suggested, check if you have duplicate first. See the following page for that

- [How to find (and delete) duplicate files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3865/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing gwenview.

`sudo apt-get install gwenview`.

But still I am not sure whether it can handle a million JPEG files. I would suggest you to  use command-line via terminal and categorize the files and then view it.