# How to find (and delete) duplicate files among local disks and NAS?

Tags: bash, delete, duplicate-files

I want to detect and delete duplicate files (same size) along local Disks and Nas Disks (The Nas Disks are mounted using Samba)

I found the [How to find and delete duplicate diles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3865/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-files) answer but I'm unable to run  most of the tools mentioned in the answer :
all the programs mentioned in the "programs/scripts/bash-solutions" solution (dupedit, dupseek, rmdup etc)

I'm able to use fslint but this one takes ages to detect duplicate files.

Can anybody help me to find to proper and faster detect and propose me to delete duplicate files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ***'dupeGuru'***

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:hsoft/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dupeguru-se
```

For further assistance you can have a walk through:
[www.unixmen.com](http://www.unixmen.com/dupeguru-find-remove-duplicate-files-instantly-hard-drive/)

Answer (score 0):

if it has to be with a GUI i would recommend [FSlint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/) or [dupeGuru](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru/)!

it won't get much faster when the program you use is checking the content of the files and therefore creates hashes!

Comment: the fallowing commands gives me bad results : sudo apt-get install dupeguru-se
 0 à enlever et 6 non mis à jour.
laurent06000@PC-DE-LDP:/etc/samba$ dupeguru-se
dupeguru-se : commande introuvable

Comment: WHich can be translated to 0 package to remove 6 not updated. The error message translation is : command not found

Comment: execute the 3 commands like posted in Dhaval Simarias answer and everything should work fine!