# Find duplicate files: keep older version

Tags: duplicate-files

I need a command line tool to remove duplicate files.

There are several. But I could not find one which always keeps the older files and deletes the newer versions.

I tried finddup, duff, fdupes. Maybe I was blind, but AFAIK there was not way to tell the tools to keep the older file.

Comment: This may help http://askubuntu.com/q/3865/178596

Comment: I'd say it is possible to script what you want. Find the duplicate files, then compare their timestamps with `stat` . I might try doing something like that later, but I'm not on my machine right now, so I can only suggest a thing

Comment: @Wilf the AskUbuntu question you mention lists a lot of tools. I tried three (or even more) tools, before asking myself. All of them seem to have not option which file to keep if you use auto-delete.

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late for the O.P. but maybe useful to others:

```
rmlint --rank-by m [paths]
```

... will search in [paths] for duplicate files and create a shell script (rmlint.sh) that you can use to delete the duplicates.  The **--rank-by m** option tells it to keep the file with the oldest **m**time in each set.  There are also several other [original selection criteria options](https://rmlint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#original-detection-selection)