# Find duplicates using KDE Dolphin

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin, duplicate-files, duplicate

Running Kubuntu 17.04.

Have a lot of duplicates - pictures and music and documents.

Does Dolphin have the ability to detect duplicates and present them for further processing like deleting?

Like what Google Contacts does?

**If not Dolphin**, is there any other good GUI tool to do the same?

Comment: Not specific to Kubuntu but worth looking at: http://pclosmag.com/html/issues/201704/page07.html

Comment: Not a GUI tool but I think exactly what you want [fdupes](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes)

Comment: The article I linked to describes `fslint` which has a GUI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find (and delete) duplicate files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3865/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-files)

Comment: @user26687 My question was primarily about Dolphin. Not just any tool to find duplicates. However, if Dolphin was not able to do it, I was asking for other options. To that extent, it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

kdiff3 will do this ,,,,,you can lode directories and compare to find duplicates and merge or delete .

```
sudo apt install kdiff3
```

VINNY VINNY@ https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forum.php